# Wait for one command to execute, before executing the next one?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, sh

I want to make a .sh script to be executed in terminal, however when I run it all of the commands seem to run at once, instead of executing one by one.

Here is the code:

```
adb disconnect
adb kill-server
adb start-server
adb connect 192.168.1.100
adb logcat | grep --line-buffered onVideoInputFormatChanged
```

The reason I think it executes all at once is because "- waiting for device -" message pops out, which would mean that the logcat command executes before the device connects.

I tried using `&&` at the end of each row, however I had no results.

Any idea how to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: adb command probably runs in the background, check it's options `man adb` to make it run on the foreground. Or if it locks some run file in `/run/lock` or use `sleep` to wait wait some time between every command

Comment: @Nasr Sleep works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
adb disconnect &
pid1=$!
wait $pid1

adb kill-server &
pid2=$!
wait $pid2
```